# Is there a way to programmatically DROP a SQL Database in Azure?

Tags: python, sql-server, azure, powershell

I am working on a process to automatically remove and add databases to Azure. When the database isn't in use, it can be removed from Azure and placed in cheaper S3 storage as a `.bacpac`.

I am using [SqlPackage.exe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlpackage/sqlpackage?view=sql-server-ver15) from Microsoft as a PowerShell script to export and import these databases from and to Azure respectively in either direction. I invoke it via a Python script to use boto3.

The issue I have is with the down direction at step 3. The sequence would be:

1. Download the Azure SQL DB to a `.bacpac` (can be achieved with SqlPackage.exe)
2. Upload this `.bacpac` to cheaper S3 storage (using boto3 Python SDK)
3. Delete the Azure SQL Database (It appears the Azure Blob Python SDK can't help me, and it appears SQLPackage.exe does not have a delete function)

Is step 3 impossible to automate with a script? Could a workaround be to  SqlPackage.exe import a small dummy `.bacpac` with the same name to overwrite the old bigger DB?
Thanks.

Comment: Are you looking for a PowerShell Cmdlet to delete SQL database?

Comment: Yes, a Microsoft SQL Azure database, PowerShell or Python would be preferred to easily integrate into this script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove an Azure SQL Database using PowerShell, you will need to use [`Remove-AzSqlDatabase`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.sql/remove-azsqldatabase?view=azps-7.3.0) Cmdlet.

To remove an Azure SQL Database using Azure CLI, you will need to us [`az sql db delete`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/sql/db?view=azure-cli-latest#az-sql-db-delete).

If you want to write code in Python to delete the database, you will need to use [`Azure SDK for Python`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/python/azure-sdk-overview).